# What would the effective memory space be in a 8GB Nexus 4?

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-4, internal-sd

So, the Nexus 4 doesn't have an external micro SD card slot, which of course is bad. So, how much of memory space would I get to use for installing applications, copying music, videos etc ?

Comment: The 16GB one has 12.92GB so the 8GB should have around 5GB. http://cdn.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/imagecache/w680h550/postimages/684/lg-nexus4-review-42.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume that it would be similar or the same as the 8GB Nexus 7, which is about [5.92GB](http://www.phonearena.com/news/199-Google-Nexus-7-tablet-has-only-5.92GB-of-free-memory-and-no-micro-SD-card-slot_id31712).